# Do caffeine patches need to be kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

The patch is being placed on the arm of a person. I don't see why they would need to be kosher but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Biur Hagra, (Orach Chaim 326, 19) cites a machlokes rishonim whether the principle of ‘sicha k’shtiya’ is specifically true on Yom Kippur (and may even be an asmachta derabanan) or if it is true of all issurim. According to this view, benefiting from non-kosher substances by absorption through skin would be prohibited. However, the majority opinion of poskim is that it is limited to Yom Kippur, and therefore items such as nicotine patches would be fine even if they are not kosher.